# Select text field that is not focused without losing selection

Tags: macos

Lets assume I selected text in a text field and focused another (in the same application, e.g. Xcode's assistant editor), so the first one is no longer the first responder. The selection will appear gray.

Is there a way to return focus to the first text field without losing the selection?

Answer (score 1):

Either use Cmd/Tab to cycle round to the app, or simpler, click the window's title bar...

[image]

[image]

Comment: That will not work if you have multiple text fields  as I mentioned and the one that you want to select is currently not in focus.

Comment: Then I've no idea what you mean, sorry